# About bootstrap method in roc() for pROC package in R

Tags: r, random-seed, statistics-bootstrap

When we set the value of smooth argument to be TRUE, roc() will use bootstrap method to for the curve calculation. 
Bootstrap is a random procedure so we usually need set.seeds() to get a reproducible output right?
But I found here even if we don’t set seed the AUC calculated based on these bootstrap procedures is fixed. Any explanation?
And is smoothed ROC curve better than jagged one?

Answer (score 0):

Quite the contrary. As far as I know in order to smooth the ROC curve a binomial model is used.
In the pROC package, and in general, bootstrap is used for testing.
I suggest to read the BMC Bioinformatics paper. I prefer smoothed ROC curves only if I need to plot a bunch of curves based on small datasets.